# Opamp Noise due to Source Resistance

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, signal-to-noise

I want to know total noise I am feeding into ADC and I have learnt about Opamp Noise and resistor noise thanks to this forum.
Now I want to know the contribution of resistor in my overall noise due to 'current noise' of Opamp and for that I need to find equivalent source resistance which I can just multiply with Current noise to get voltage noise (am I right) and also the equivalent feedback resistance through which this noise current is flowing to get voltage noise due to it.
I read somewhere that equivalent resistance in a wheatstone bridge is nothing but the value of a single resistor but only if all resistor are of same value and my case doesn't seem to fit the criteria, the wheatstone bridge I am using is SM5652 pressure sensor.
what will the equivalent source and feedback resistances in this case?

[image]

Comment: Have you actually built this? If so, how much total noise are you measuring? I'm curious because depending on your choice of components (how you set the input common mode signal), this may not work with most differential ADCs

Comment: @sbell Yes I tested it, and at 16 bit resolution It gave 10-20 counts fluctuation.
What do you see wrong in common mode signal?
For this sensor common mode voltage stated is Vcc/2.

Comment: Most differential ADCs requires the incoming common-mode voltage to equal Vref/2, or very close to it. For example, the [AD7982](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD7982.pdf) requires the common-mode to be within 5% of Vref/2. I learned by sad experience that when you violate that, the SNR will be nowhere near what's stated on the datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22093b.pdf) to your opamps.
First I'm guessing the R of the pressure sensor is less than the 2k ohm you have in series.
If so you can mostly ignore the R of the sensor.
The opamp has very small current noise.. (see page 4.)

i-noise < 1 fA/rtHz, so even with 1 Meg of resistance that's still ~1nV/rtHz of voltage noise.  (Just ignore the current noise.)

The voltage noise of that part (~80 nV/rtHz) seems high to me, but maybe that is typical for autozero (chopper stabilized?) opamps.  Or perhaps someone else can recommend a better part.

Edit: about RC filters.  Since you are filtering the input to ~1kHz (2k ohm and 0.1uF) you might as well do that on the output too.  (bump up R13 and 14)

Comment: Actually its an old diagram, I am setting cutoff at 10Hz.yes the I noise of this opamp is very less but I want to do comparisons of few opamps that's why I need to know the way.

Comment: @Sajid,  My point is that most of your noise is coming from the voltage noise of the opamps, filtering in front of the opamps doesn't really do anything to your total noise.  (Why not post the most recent diagram?)

Comment: Ok. I'll remove that RC before opamp.
But I am comparing OPamps and there are others out there which have low voltage noise but their current noise is 1.7 pA/rtHz.
So I can't ignore it.

Comment: @Sajid, Oh the RC in front is OK,  (well you could just use a bigger C,  with the R in your bridge/ sensor) What is the sensor resistance?  ~1-2pA/rtHz is fine as long as the impedances are not much more than 1 k ohm or so.

Comment: Sensor Datasheet says o/p resistance of 2.5k.

Comment: @Sajid, 2.5k ohm.. OK I think you'll do better with a bjt type opamp.  (but the fet's are getting better every day.)  Oh one other thing to look out for is that you need to drive your bridge with a low noise voltage source.  (not always as easy as it sounds.)

Answer (score 1):

The wheatstone bridge you are using will probably not have massive resistance value differences under all weight situations so you can use the nominal resistance with hardly any error.

For an instrumentation amplifier configuration you can ignore the feedback resistors if RG is the dominant lowest resistance (which it usually is to achieve high gain) and then you are left with current noise into your nominal bridge resistance multiplied by voltage gain as the noise produced across the differential output.

If RG is significant compared with Bridge_Resistance then the current noise that produces a voltage noise via RG will also become significant but, this isn't usually the case on high gain systems.